# react native install warning and compilation error

Tags: react-native

**I am getting following error while compiling awesome project .**

Error building DependencyGraph:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'root' of null
    at index.js:16:84
    at tryCallOne (/Users/mahesh.govind/react/AwesomeProj .
```

I am using xcode  Version `7.1.1 (7B1005) .`

While installing react native  I got following **warnings**
.

```
/usr/local/bin/react-native -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-karma/node_modules/findup-sync requires glob@'~4.3.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-karma/node_modules/glob,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 5.0.15
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/node_modules/bower requires chalk@'^1.0.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/node_modules/chalk,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.5.1
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/node_modules/bower requires glob@'^4.3.2' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/node_modules/glob,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 5.0.15
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/node_modules/bower requires inquirer@'0.10.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/node_modules/inquirer,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.8.5
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/node_modules/bower requires mkdirp@'0.5.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/node_modules/mkdirp,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.5.1
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/node_modules/bower requires request@'2.53.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/node_modules/request,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.65.0
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/node_modules/mongodb-core requires bson@'~0.4' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/node_modules/bson,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.3.2
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/node_modules/node.extend requires is@'^3.0.1' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/node_modules/is,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.0.2
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/node_modules/utile requires async@'~0.2.9' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/node_modules/async,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.9.0
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/node_modules/winston requires async@'0.2.x' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/node_modules/async,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.9.0
```

Any pointers ... Thanks in advance ..
-mahesh

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're running into [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5191):

> There was a regression with 0.18c.

For now, I'd either cherry pick the referenced commit or downgrade your react native dependencies in package.json to 0.17 for a few days.